# Class Object to create objects of type Object, in a dynamic way, with magic methods

Tags: php, object-oriented

I have a project in my mind for quite some time, and it requires me to create dynamic objects.

Usually, casting an array to object does the trick (e.g.: `(object)array('test'=>5)`). But sometimes, we still want the magic methods to fire up. For that, I have developed a class.

It supports the magic methods `__construct`, `__get`, `__set`, `__isset` and `__unset`. This also has a method to check the keys in your object.

```php
class Object {
    private $props = array();
    private $methods = array(
        '__construct'=>null,
        '__get'=>null,
        '__set'=>null,
        '__isset'=>null,
        '__unset'=>null
    );

    private function __run_magic_method( $method, $args=null )
    {
        $obj = (object)$this->props;
        $return = call_user_func_array( $this->methods[$method], array_merge( array(&$obj), (array)$args ) );
        $this->props = (array)$obj;
        return $return;
    }

    private function __has_magic_method( $method )
    {
        return isset( $this->methods[$method] ) && is_callable( $this->methods[$method] );
    }

    function __construct( array $props )
    {
        foreach( array_keys($this->methods) as $method )
        {
            if( isset( $props[$method] ) )
            {
                $this->methods[$method] = $props[$method];
                unset( $props[$method] );
            }
        }

        $this->props = $props;

        if( $this->__has_magic_method( '__construct' ) )
        {
            $this->__run_magic_method( '__construct' );
        }
    }

    function __get( $key )
    {
        if($this->__has_magic_method('__get' ) )
        {
            return $this->__run_magic_method( '__get', array($key) );
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->props[$key];
        }
    }

    function __set( $key, $value )
    {
        if( $this->__has_magic_method( '__set' ) )
        {
            $this->__run_magic_method( '__set', array( $key, $value ) );
        }
        else
        {
            $this->props[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    function __isset( $key )
    {
        if( $this->__has_magic_method( '__isset' ) )
        {
            return $this->__run_magic_method( '__isset', array($key) );
        }
        else
        {
            return isset( $this->props[$key] );
        }
    }

    function __unset( $key )
    {
        if( $this->__has_magic_method( '__unset' ) )
        {
            return $this->__run_magic_method( '__unset', array($key) );
        }
        else
        {
            unset( $this->props[$key] );
        }
    }

    function __call( $key, $args )
    {
        if( isset( $this->props[$key] ) && is_callable( $this->props[$key] ) )
        {
            return call_user_func_array( $this->props[$key], $args );
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception( 'The key "'.addslashes($key).'" is not a callable' );
        }
    }

    private function __keys()
    {
        return array_keys( $this->props );
    }

    static function keys( Object $obj=null )
    {
        if( $obj === null )
        {
            return array();
        }
        else
        {
            return $obj->__keys();
        }
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
$obj = new Object(array(
    '__construct'=>function(){echo 'constructor executed', PHP_EOL;},
    '__isset'=>function($t,$k){
        echo 'checking key: ', $k, PHP_EOL;
        return isset($t->{$k});
    },
    'test'=>5
));

if( isset($obj->test) )
{
    echo $obj->test;
}

/*
Should output:

constructor executed
checking key: test
5
*/
```

What can I improve in this code, in terms of readability? What crimes am I committing with this code?

Comment: "PHP reserves all function names starting with __ as magical. It is recommended that you do not use function names with __ in PHP unless you want some documented magic functionality." (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Comment: @Agares I am aware of that. I should have used `_` as a prefix instead.

Comment: @Agares I've added it on github (https://github.com/ismael-miguel/object-class-php) with a few changes. The only changes were the one in your comment, removed the exception and now I use a `trigger_error` instead and added support for the magic method `__toString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out before, in a comment, non-magic methods in a class shouldn't be prefixed with `__`.

Since they are private, they are prefixed with `_`.

---

Closures are a really nice feature that came with PHP5.3, and they weren't being used to their full potential.

Closures have the method `bindTo`, which generates a new Closure binded to that object.
This allows to use the variable `$this` inside the Closure.
It helps the fellow programmers that decide to use this to write in a more natural way.
The best part is that there are no kludges needed!

The method `_run_magic_method()` will look like this:

```
    private function _run_magic_method( $method, $args=null )
    {
        $obj = (object)$this->props;

        if( is_a( $this->methods[$method], 'Closure' ) )
        {
            $return = call_user_func_array( $this->methods[$method]->bindTo( $obj ), (array)$args );
        }
        else
        {
            $return = call_user_func_array( $this->methods[$method], array_merge( array(&$obj), (array)$args ) );
        }
        $this->props = (array)$obj;
        return $return;
    }
```

Since objects are passed as references in PHP5, all changes are reflected on the properties.

---

The final code:

```
<?php

    class Object {
        private $props = array();
        private $methods = array(
            '__construct'=>null,
            '__get'=>null,
            '__set'=>null,
            '__isset'=>null,
            '__unset'=>null,
            '__toString'=>null
        );
        private function _run_magic_method( $method, $args=null )
        {
            $obj = (object)$this->props;

            if( is_a( $this->methods[$method], 'Closure' ) )
            {
                //Inside the closure, the $this will be changing the parent $this->props
                $return = call_user_func_array( $this->methods[$method]->bindTo( $obj ), (array)$args );
            }
            else
            {
                $return = call_user_func_array( $this->methods[$method], array_merge( array( &$obj ), (array)$args ) );
            }

            $this->props = (array)$obj;
            return $return;
        }
        private function _has_magic_method( $method )
        {
            return isset( $this->methods[$method] ) && is_callable( $this->methods[$method] );
        }
        function __construct( array $props )
        {
            foreach( array_keys( $this->methods ) as $method )
            {
                if( isset( $props[$method] ) )
                {
                    $this->methods[$method] = $props[$method];
                    unset( $props[$method] );
                }
            }
            $this->props = $props;
            if( $this->_has_magic_method( '__construct' ) )
            {
                $this->_run_magic_method( '__construct' );
            }
        }
        function __get( $key )
        {
            if($this->_has_magic_method('__get' ) )
            {
                return $this->_run_magic_method( '__get', array($key) );
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->props[$key];
            }
        }
        function __set( $key, $value )
        {
            if( $this->_has_magic_method( '__set' ) )
            {
                $this->_run_magic_method( '__set', array( $key, $value ) );
            }
            else
            {
                $this->props[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        function __isset( $key )
        {
            if( $this->_has_magic_method( '__isset' ) )
            {
                return $this->_run_magic_method( '__isset', array($key) );
            }
            else
            {
                return isset( $this->props[$key] );
            }
        }
        function __unset( $key )
        {
            if( $this->_has_magic_method( '__unset' ) )
            {
                return $this->_run_magic_method( '__unset', array($key) );
            }
            else
            {
                unset( $this->props[$key] );
            }
        }
        function __call( $key, $args )
        {
            if( isset( $this->props[$key] ) && is_callable( $this->props[$key] ) )
            {
                return call_user_func_array( $this->props[$key], $args );
            }
            else
            {
                trigger_error( 'The key "'.addslashes($key).'" is not a callable', E_USER_ERROR );
            }
        }
        function __toString( )
        {
            if( $this->_has_magic_method( '__toString' ) )
            {
                return $this->_run_magic_method( '__toString' ) . '';
            }
            else
            {
                trigger_error( 'There is no defined __toString method', E_USER_ERROR );
            }
        }
        private function _keys()
        {
            return array_keys( $this->props );
        }
        static function keys( Object $obj=null )
        {
            if( $obj === null )
            {
                return array();
            }
            else
            {
                return $obj->_keys();
            }
        }
    }
```

Example of execution:

```
$obj = new Object(array(
    'a'=>5,
    '__get'=>function($k){
        echo 'Getting the value from the key \'',$k,'\'', PHP_EOL;
        return $this->{$k};
    },
    '__set'=>function($k,$v){
        echo 'Setting a value on the key \'',$k,'\'', PHP_EOL;
        $this->{$k}=$v;
    }
));

/*
 *Should output:
 *
 * Getting the value from the key 'a'
 * 5
 * Setting a value on the key 'b'
 * Getting the value from the key 'b'
 * 6
 *
 */
```

Comment: Since the number of other answers was null, I'm (sadly) marking this as the accepted answer.